# How to force eager loading in HQL

Tags: hibernate, annotations, hql, eager-loading

I'm trying to force an HQL to eager load all the Lazy properties.
Using FETCH gives me the "multiple bags" exception and I can't change it to Set as they're referenced elsewhere. I tryed other mapping Annotations but no luck.
The "FETCH ALL PROPERTIES" is ignored and nothing is loaded. I never understood what it really does. Obviously when JSF tries to read the List I get the "cannot initialize lazy List. Connection closed"

I'm using Hibernate 4.0.
So here's my HQL query:

```
Select r from Responsavel r FETCH ALL PROPERTIES 
where r.unidadeEmpresarial.id = :idUnidade
```

And here's my model class:

```
public class Responsavel {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SQ_RESPONSAVEL_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SE_RESPONSAVEL", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SQ_RESPONSAVEL_GENERATOR")
@Column(name = "SQ_RESPONSAVEL")
private Long id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "DT_FIM")
private Date dataFim;

@NotNull
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "DT_INICIO")
private Date dataInicio;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "DT_NASCIMENTO")
private Date dataNascimento;

@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
@Column(name = "IN_PODER_ADM_REPRES")
private Boolean temPoderAdministrativo;

@Column(name = "NO_RESPONSAVEL")
private String nome;

@Column(name = "NU_CPF_CNPJ_RESPONSAVEL")
private String numeroCpfCnpj;

@NotNull
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "TP_PESSOA")
private String tipoPessoa;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SQ_PAIS")
private Pais pais;

@Column(name = "VL_CAPITAL_SOCIAL")
private BigDecimal valorCapitalSocial;

@Column(name = "PC_CAPITAL_SOCIAL")
private BigDecimal percentualCapitalSocial;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SQ_UNIDADE_EMPRESARIAL")
private UnidadeEmpresarial unidadeEmpresarial;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "responsavel", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private Set<ResponsavelQualificacaoResponsavel> listaResponsavelQualificacaoResponsavel;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "responsavel")
private List<Representante> representantes;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "responsavel")
private List<ContatoResponsavel> contatoResponsavel;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "responsavel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<EnderecoResponsavel> enderecoResponsavel;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but cant you just change the fetch type to EAGER (fetch = FetchType.EAGER) on the mapping annotation in your model class?

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the multiple bags exception, then it is because Hibernate cannot get all of your collections at once. You should pick a collection you wish to select with your base query and do so with a join, then use Hibernate.initialize to obtain the remainder of the collections you require.

So it would look like this (I'm leaving off the select, since it isn't required):

```
from Responsavel r 
join fetch pais p
join fetch unidadeEmpresarial u
join fetch representantes s
where r.unidadeEmpresarial.id = :idUnidade
```

You can experiment with which ones to include. What's left, requires initialization if you wish to detach from the Hibernate session to, for example, use the collections in the front-end or in a service class.

```
Hibernate.initialize(listaResponsavelQualificacaoResponsavel);
Hibernate.initialize(contatoResponsavel);
Hibernate.initialize(enderecoResponsavel);
```

If you will be remaining the session, then no need to initialize, they will initialize on demand (though this could lead to a performance issue depending on your use case).

Comment: Did this help? Can I be of further assistance?